# Why funciton gets is not working and skipping the user input?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char aa[35];
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    gets(aa);
    puts(aa);
}
```

It is not taking string from user but if I take the string before the integer value it is working fine.

Comment: What input are you trying to give your program?  Try clearing the stream errors with [`clearerr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/clearerr) if the `scanf` fails.

Comment: `gets` is probably reading the newline that was left after `scanf`.  Also, never use `gets`, since there is no way to prevent buffer overflow.  Use `fgets` instead.  The man page for `gets` makes it clear that it should never be used.

Comment: Also note that any program with gets can be crashed or exploited by user input. In other words, never use gets. Use for example fgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `scanf("%d",&a);` takes numeric characters out of `stdin` to form the `int` for `a`, it is done.  It does not consume a `'\n'` that may follow it.

`gets(aa);`, consumes data until `'\n'`.

So input like <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the below will put `123` into `a` and `"xy"` into `aa`.

```
scanf("%d",&a);
gets(aa);
```

Input like <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the above will put `456` into `a` and `""` into `aa`.

---

Recommend using `fgets()` and add error handling.

```
if (fgets(aa, sizeof aa, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
if (sscanf(aa, "%d", &a) != 1) Handle_Nonnumeric_Input();

if (fgets(aa, sizeof aa, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
aa[strcspn(aa, "\n")] = '\0'; // truncate potential \n
```

Answer (score 0):

try placing another gets() :

```
gets(aa);
gets(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

For further information, u should search Google about buffered IO
in this situation, because when you input a number first, you also have to pres "Enter", which means there are one "\n" character stays after a number is accepted
So, before making input any string, remember to clear the buffered IO, there are 2 ways to do that
`Flush(stdin);`
or
`_flushall();`

Comment: May want to review [Using fflush(stdin)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/2410359)

Comment: Yeah, double f, my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Use fflush in between scanf and gets to clear the buffer. It will work perfectly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char aa[20];     
    int b;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(aa);
    puts(aa); 
    getchar();
}
```

Suggesting you not to use gets() since it does not validate the size of memory.

Comment: May want to review [Using fflush(stdin)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/2410359)